# Can I change dynamically color of separate day of week in Calendar view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, calendarview

I am little bit stuck and don't know to do. I have a `Calendar View` and wanna to change the color of `day of week` dynamically, in my case need to handle click on day of week. Below image what I am mean (sorry have only Russian version of example):

[image]

In above screenshot selected Tuesday an Thursday (week starts from Monday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like it is not quite possible. when you analyze the source code of [SimpleMonthView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleMonthView.java) which is the view used in CalendarView to draw each month, you can see that there is a stateMask (VIEW_STATE_ACTIVATED, VIEW_STATE_PRESSED) for days of Month but there isn't any stateMask for days of the week.

I would recommend to draw custom days of week view and overlap it with calendar view. I know it is not best solution